# Как правильно толковать слово "переселенцы"?

Tags: выбор-слов, значение-слов

Можно ли людей, которых переселили из старых домов в новые (в том же городе), назвать переселенцами?

Или лучше — переселившиеся сказали то-то...

В одном словаре есть такое толкование:

1. Человек, переселившийся или переселяемый с постоянного места жительства в новые, обычно необжитые места. Переселенцы на новые земли. Крестьяне-переселенцы. Переселенцы в окраинные губернии (в старой России).

Comment: Вопрос скорее не о толковании, а о применении слова, то есть не о понимании написанного, а о сочинении новых текстов.

Comment: На сайте русского языка, пожалуйста, соблюдайте правила орфографии — начинайте предложение с заглавной буквы.

Answer (score 2):

**Переселенцы** — люди, прибывшие на новое место жительства в результате переселения.

**Это общее название**, его можно применять в различных ситуациях.

Например, это название может быть термином, если оно применяется к вынужденным переселенцам, так как их статус определяется специальным законом.

С другой стороны, люди могут добровольно переезжать из ветхого жилья в новое по государственной программе, их тоже можно назвать переселенцами.

Не стоит изобретать  названия и усложнять речь, если в языке уже имеется подходящее слово. По тексту всегда видно, о каких переселенцах говорится в каждом конкретном случае.

Answer (score 2):

Не могу поверить, что каждого, кто переселился (переехал) из одной квартиры в другую, можно назвать переселенцем. Переселение должно быть важным событием или даже мероприятием. Трудно формально описать границы применения этого термина,  но, на мой взгляд, переселенцами можно назвать всех вынужденно переселившихся, а также добровольно переселившихся по программе переселения, а если не по программе, то в рамках какой-то тенденции и на значительные расстояния.

> Новая квартира для переселенцев из старого и аварийного жилья никак не может быть по площади меньше и хуже старой — заявил Верховный суд РФ...

По-моему, здесь речь идет именно о вынужденном и организованном переселении.

Answer (score 1):

*Переселенцы* и *поселенцы* - эти слова традиционно связаны с переселением на большие расстояния (словарная статья это и поясняет). Условно (при известности контекста) так *можно* говорить и в вашем случае, но если об этих людях говорится кратко или впервые, то *точнее* будет говорить о **переселённых** или **переселяемых** (по чужой инициативе) или о **переселившихся**, **переселяющихся** (по своей инициативе, охотно, приложив к этому усилия или при поддержке властей и т. п.).

Answer (score 1):

Второе значение в [словаре Ожегова](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/156966/%D0%9F%D0%95%D0%A0%D0%95%D0%A1%D0%95%D0%9B%D0%95%D0%9D%D0%95%D0%A6):
**переселенец**
**2.** Человек, временно переселяемый куда-нибудь из своего жилья.
Жилплощадь для переселенцев.

[Ефремова](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/212087) в толковом словаре дает общую, без нюансов, характеристику:
**переселе́нец**, *м.*
**Тот, кто переселен или переселился на новое место жительства.**

Так что люди, получившие новое жилье (переселенные из старого) — переселенцы.

*Новая квартира для переселенцев из старого и аварийного жилья никак не может быть по площади меньше и хуже старой — заявил Верховный суд РФ...*